# How to reset previous response from ajax and load the current one on each click?

Tags: jquery, ajax, donut-chart

I am trying to implement a filter to my graph so the graph will change as per the dates selected. The elements are called using ajax. After the first response is loaded I want to clear the first response IF AND ONLY IF again the filter parameters are changed on click event.
My ajax code is:

```
    var dataset = jQuery("form#sortby").serialize();
    var elements = [];
    var counter;
    jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'doughnut-top-ten.php',
          data: dataset,
          success: function(response){
            jQuery('#loading').hide();
            jQuery('#morris_donut_graph').hide();
            jQuery('#morris_donut_graph_filtered').show();
            $('#StudentID').val()
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    counter = jsonData[i];
                    var sale = roundFloat(counter.sales,2);
                    elements.push({
                        value: sale,
                        label: counter.product_name
                    });
            }
            /*Donut Graph*/
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'morris_donut_graph_filtered',
                data: elements,
                resize: true,
                redraw: true,
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                labelColor: '#999999',
                colors:['#1FB5AC','#F74C4C','#F8A188','#9972B5','#37FFFF','#F30D0D','#5B5BF9','#A5F133','#F24C96','#FBD109',],
                formatter: function(x) {
                    return "$" + x
                }
            });
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the server's code, one way would be to add a `requestId` to the request dataset with each AJAX request. The response returns the data and this request identifier.

You then check if the response you've received matches the current `requestId`, and if it does, you perform your operations as usual. Otherwise you simply ignore the response, for it is old.

Here's a simplified version of the implementation:

```
var dataset = jQuery("form#sortby").serialize();
var currentRequestId = generateNewRequestId(); 
dataset.requestId = currentRequestId;
var elements = [];
var counter;
jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'doughnut-top-ten.php',
      data: dataset,
      success: function(response){
        // Ignore if the requestId received in the
        // response doesn't match the currentRequestId
        if(response.requestId != currentRequestId) return;

        jQuery('#loading').hide();
        jQuery('#morris_donut_graph').hide();
        jQuery('#morris_donut_graph_filtered').show();
        $('#StudentID').val()
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                counter = jsonData[i];
                var sale = roundFloat(counter.sales,2);
                elements.push({
                    value: sale,
                    label: counter.product_name
                });
        }
        /*Donut Graph*/
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'morris_donut_graph_filtered',
            data: elements,
            resize: true,
            redraw: true,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            labelColor: '#999999',
            colors:['#1FB5AC','#F74C4C','#F8A188','#9972B5','#37FFFF','#F30D0D','#5B5BF9','#A5F133','#F24C96','#FBD109',],
            formatter: function(x) {
                return "$" + x
            }
        });
       }
```

`generateNewRequestId()` could return a random string/integer each time, or it could return a concatenation of dataset inputs. In the latter case, you'll have an advantage that the responses of two requests with the same dataset can be reused.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't connect back and answering so late. Unfortunately this idea didn't work in my case. I want to flush the previous loaded response. The response I am getting is from an ajax call to a page with mysql queries.